# jsTree set node from Ajax Data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I'm trying to use JsTree, with Ajax.
The first image shows the initial state of JsTree without the Ajax call.

[image: Initial]

The user click on the first node, and selects all items, according second image.

[image: User click in node]

Before post values, I call a function to grab all the selected items in JsTree.
Result of function, it is third image.

[image: Selected values]

If I call the data by Ajax, the result of the JsTree conforms to the image four

[image: Values set from ajax data]

### Question

What should I set / configure, so the Ajax return is the same when the user clicks on the nodes. After the return of Ajax, there is no selected node.

#### My JsTree Config

```
$('#tree').jstree({
    'plugins': ["checkbox"],
    'core': {
        'data': {
            'url': '/Ajax/AcessoFuncao/',
            'data': function (node) {                        
                return { 'acessoperfil': $("#AcessoPerfilID").val() };
            }
        }
    }
});
```

#### My Code Before Post

```
function BeforePost()
{
    document.getElementById("items").value = $("#tree").jstree(true).get_checked().join(',');
    alert(document.getElementById("items").value);
}
```

#### My Json Data

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "parent":"#",
      "text":"AcessoFuncao",
      "icon":"fa  fa-tags",
      "state":{  
         "opened":false,
         "disabled":false,
         "selected":true
      },
      "li_attr":null,
      "a_attr":{  
         "id":null,
         "class":"no_checkbox"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":"1_1",
      "parent":"1",
      "text":"Listar",
      "icon":"fa fa-list",
      "state":{  
         "opened":false,
         "disabled":false,
         "selected":true
      },
      "li_attr":null,
      "a_attr":{  
         "id":null,
         "class":"jstree-checked jstree-clicked"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":"1_4",
      "parent":"1",
      "text":"Inserir",
      "icon":"fa fa-plus",
      "state":{  
         "opened":false,
         "disabled":false,
         "selected":true
      },
      "li_attr":null,
      "a_attr":{  
         "id":null,
         "class":"jstree-checked jstree-clicked"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":"1_2",
      "parent":"1",
      "text":"Visualizar",
      "icon":"fa fa-eye",
      "state":{  
         "opened":false,
         "disabled":false,
         "selected":true
      },
      "li_attr":null,
      "a_attr":{  
         "id":null,
         "class":"jstree-checked jstree-clicked"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":"1_8",
      "parent":"1",
      "text":"Alterar",
      "icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-edit",
      "state":{  
         "opened":false,
         "disabled":false,
         "selected":true
      },
      "li_attr":null,
      "a_attr":{  
         "id":null,
         "class":"jstree-checked jstree-clicked"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":"1_16",
      "parent":"1",
      "text":"Excluír",
      "icon":"fa fa-trash-o",
      "state":{  
         "opened":false,
         "disabled":false,
         "selected":false
      },
      "li_attr":null,
      "a_attr":null
   }
]
```

Comment: Olá @Marlon boa noite, pode me ajudar e mostrar como voce monta o arry para gerar o jstree?

Comment: @WagnerFilho estava longe da comunidade por um tempo. Precisa de ajuda ainda?

Comment: na verdade sim.
Eu queria saber se voce monta a arvore jstree através do MYSQL

Comment: Vou fazer um post esta noite e passo o link pode ser @WagnerFilho?

Comment: pode sim, agradeço..

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly set the state of the last node (`1_16`) as `selected : false` - if you want it to be selected - make sure you return `selected : true`.

Comment: my problem is after load ajax data, no items are marked as selected using `BeforePost` code.

Comment: ```get_checked``` returns the same regardless of how data is loaded (provided it is the same data and that it is indeed loaded). I can't help you further without a demo.

Comment: I'll create the demo. In tests, I noticed that at line 3431 of jstree.js, if the data comes from ajax, `state.core.selected` has no data.

However, if I use the data equal to the ajax result, the `state.core.selected` has data